# PHP memcached session expires out of the blue

Tags: php, session, memcached, session-timeout

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

The rest it standard. I expect the session to be kept alive for at least 86400 seconds since the last time user visited the page, ie If I started a session and visited page 5 minutes later, the session should expire only after another `86400` seconds.

However, now session expires after roughly an hour. I've attached screenshot for the **phpMemcachedAdmin**.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are other parameters that might apply:

Your session cookie might expire early. Calling session_set_cookie_params(86400) will ensure that your session cookie exists as long as your actual session.

Also, gc_maxlifetime set a maximum for your session lifetime. Don't forget that the garbage collection is triggered by a probability: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability:

> session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 100.

You might try to check/change these settings too.

Comment: My config was overwriting `session_set_cookie_params`. But this only partially answers my question. Supposedly, I set `session_set_cookie_params(60)`. Why does my session expire 60 seconds from the first load, rather than 60 seconds from the last-subsequent call? Is there a way to extend session.

Comment: The cookie expiration date is only set when it's created. Any subsequent call will extend your session (server-side), but the cookie will disappear after 60 seconds. So the server-side will still exists, but the client will drop the session cookie and loose the session id.

Comment: How do I prolong the cookie expiration to match server timing?

Comment: session_set_cookie_params(86400) should to do exactly that. Login to your app, and check your session cookie with a cookie inspection tool. You'll be able to determine if the expiration date is what you expect.

Comment: Is there any downside of doing this every time page is called?

Comment: I don't think there is, performance-wise, any downside. You could also change this setting in your php.ini (session.cookie_lifetime) which should rule out any unknown downside of calling session_set_cookie_params() every time a page is loaded.

Comment: Setting `session.cookie_lifetime` to `86400` will automatically extend cookie life time every time page is loaded?

Comment: No. Setting session.cookie_lifetime to 86400 will set your cookie expiration date to time()+86400 once it's created. It's expiration date will not be changed afterwards.

Comment: (1) the default cookie_lifetime is 0, which means 'until the browser is closed', which should be OK for almost everyone, (2) the garbage collector will only clean op _expired_ sessions, on a probability to run (as not every request needs to run a garbage collector, although it might be better to remove it from a user-request al together (probability 0) and run it from a cron) active session will _never_ be cleaned up (3) session expiry is determined by `session.gc_maxlifetime`, not `session.cookie_lifetime` (which at the previously stated default 0 is OK).

Answer (score 0):

```
; Document expires after n minutes.
; http://php.net/session.cache-expire
session.cache_expire = 1440
```

This setting might be affected if you use memcached session handler.

Comment: "This only changes HTTP cache expiration time" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php#81265